for downgrading dart version, Is it necessary to write flutter downgrade
my current Dart SDK version is 3.4.1.
I want it to downgrade to >=2.12.0 <3.4.0
I am unable to do it I mean I had changed in pub spec but also nothing changed as desired
I tried to changed by doing it from terminal but didn't succeed
please help

I will suggest using fvm/paru

Changing the pubspec changes the version of Dart/Flutter that your package needs to run. It won't change what version of Dart/Flutter you actually have installed. To do that, you will need to run flutter downgrade to install a version of Flutter that runs a version of Dart within that range, such as flutter downgrade 3.19.6.

And as the other comment suggests, if you find yourself jumping around Flutter versions often, you should use a tool like FVM or asdf to manage multiple versions of Flutter and pick the version you want to use for specific projects.
